# How to get emacs to list suggestions like ls (along columns)

Tags: sorting, emacs, autosuggest, ls

How can I get emacs to list suggestions along columns instead of rows?

In short, emacs gives me this:

```
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
abc1                  abc2                  abc3
abc4                  abc5                  abc6
abc7                  abc8                  abc9
bc1                   bc2                   bc3
```

But I would like it like this, so I can quickly scan a column:

```
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
abc1                  abc5                  abc9
abc2                  abc6                  bc1
abc3                  abc7                  bc2
abc4                  abc8                  bc3
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding the following to your .emacs should do the trick.

```
(setq completions-format 'vertical)
```

*Note:* This option was introduced in Emacs 23.2.

Comment: Suppose I don't see last line `abc4  abc8  bc3`. That way, I don't have my results shown in alphabetical order.

Comment: @desudesudesu good point. I wonder if you or anyone else knows how to let entries in the *Completions* buffer expand towards the right-hand side, so that one would be scrolling horizontally to view the remaining entries?